# How to use Selenium web browser to post in salesforce

Tags: html, selenium-ide

My friend recommended Kantu for work automation hence I'm trying it out but couldn't seem to find the answer to my question on the web.
I'm new at coding, automation, stackoverflow and this is my first post.

Have just installed Kantu for Chrome- Selenium IDE Light and am trying to automate a daily post message within salesforce.

However, have received this error when I try to click on the message box.

[error]
time out when looking for element '//*[@id="outerContainer"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p'

When I click on inspect, I find this code for the message box:

I've tried running the Test Case demos and everything seems to be able to run well without problems. Noticed that the key difference in the Selenium IDE demos are that the text boxes are fixed (i.e. constantly appearing on the pages) whilst the text boxes within salesforce only appear when clicked upon.

Have tried to add in macros to click on the text div box within salesforce but Selenium doesn't seem to be able to record the click part hence unable to insert any texts into the salesforce.

Hope someone can help.
Many thanks in advance, happy new year!

Comment: Thanks Nic! Will try it out. Happy new year!

Comment: @NicEndo, tested it but didn't work.